# WCF Base Addresses

Tags: wcf

What is the difference between the service base address and the endpoint base address?

Suppose i have a base address for the service like this: `"http://hostname:port/svc1"` and the endpoint of the service is configured with the NetMsmqBinding which requires a transport scheme "net.msmq" and not "http". This would result into an exception from the WCF runtime, right?

But then, this means that all endpoints of a service must conform to the transport scheme specified in the service base address, right?

Can somebody please help solve this ambiguity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have one base address **per scheme** - so you can define one base address for `http`, another for `net.tcp` and so on.

The **base address** is the base of the address - each endpoint will have to provide a **relative address** which gets added to this base address:

- Base address for `http`: `http://hostname:port/svc1`
- Base address for `net.tcp`: `net.tcp://hostname:port/tcp`
- Endpoint 1: `address="test1"` --> complete URL `http://hostname:port/svc1/test1`
- Endpoint 2: `address="test2"` --> complete URL `http://hostname:port/svc1/test2`
- Endpoint 1 for `net.tcp`: `address="tcp1"` --> complete URL `net.tcp://hostname:port/tcp/tcp1`
- Endpoint 2 for `net.tcp`: `address="tcp2"` --> complete URL `net.tcp://hostname:port/tcp/tcp2`

And of course, even with a base address in place, if the endpoint defines it's own, **complete** address, then that address will be used:

- Endpoint 3: `address="http://hostname:port2/OtherService/EP1"` --> in that case, since a complete address is specified , the defined base address for `http` does **not** apply and this fully qualified address **IS** the actual, complete endpoint address